# Silverlight Gallery

Tags: c#, silverlight

The Silverlight toolkit comes with a [great gallery](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) showing all of the widgets along with code samples.  Is there anything like this available for the core widgets?  Java had one of these and I found it extremely helpful to see everything that was available.

Answer (score 1):

There's one [here](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl2/silverlightcontrols/run/default.html) but it's a bit old (SL 2)